# Using abstract base class properties with IronPython isn't as expected

Tags: c#, ironpython

I've got an interface and an abstract base class in C# 4.0:

```
public interface IScript
{
    ScriptResources Resources { get; set; }
    string MessageLog { get; }

    void Init();
    ScriptResult Execute();
    void Cleanup();
}

public abstract class Script : IScript
{
    public ScriptResources Resources { get; set; }
    public string MessageLog { get; protected set; }

    public abstract void Init();

    public ScriptResult Execute()
    {
        try
        {
            Init();
            ScriptResult = RunScript();
        }
        finally
        {
            Cleanup();
        }

        return ScriptResult;
    }

    protected abstract ScriptResult RunScript();

    public abstract void Cleanup();
}
```

On the IronPython side, I've got the following class which inherits from the C# Script class:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("MyCSharpLibrary.dll")
from MyCSharpLibrary import *

class IronPythonScript(Script):
    def __new__(self):
        return Script.__new__(self)

    def __init__(self):
        return Script.__init__(self)

    def Init(self):
        Script.LogMessage(self, "< IronPython: Init() >")
        Script.LogMessage(self, "")
        # Do stuff

    def RunScript(self):
        Script.LogMessage(self, "< IronPython: RunScript() >")
        # Do stuff

    def Cleanup(self):
        Script.LogMessage(self, "< IronPython: Cleanup() >")
        # Do stuff
```

However, in order to use the base class Script properties (MessageLog, Resources) in IronPython I have to use the following rather ugly syntax which seems wrong to me:

```
Script.MessageLog.__set__(self, "TEST VALUE")
print Script.MessageLog.__get__(self)
```

What am I doing wrong? (note: I have limited experience with Python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about:

```
self.MessageLog = "TEST VALUE"
print self.MessageLog
```

Comment: Well this is embarrassing. I swear I tried that previously but was getting type exceptions.

Comment: I guess I should have read a little bit more on class vs instance attributes in Python and I would have realized I was using class attributes which is incorrect in this case. Thanks.